# Extending linear algebraic group action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, group-actions

Suppose we have a linear algebraic group $G$ acting birationally on a complete variety $X$ i.e. we are given a rational morphism $G\times X\dashrightarrow X$ satisfying obvious properties. Is there a (canonical) variety $Y$ equipped with a regular action of $G$ and a regular equivariant map $\varphi\colon Y\to X$ which is birational isomorphism? I am interested in particular case when $G=\mathbb G_m$. The same question in complex analytic setting.

Comment: Yes, it's a theorem of Weil (under mild assumptions): A. Weil, On algebraic groups of transformations, Amer. J. Math. 77 (1955), 355-391. Behind paywall if you want to give some more money to JSTOR: jstor.org/stable/2372637